Unable to install packages on Arch Linux: snapd.db download failure and host resolution error
I've only just got Arch Linux and hyprland. Anytime I try to sudo install just about anything, in this case vscode, it gives me this error:
snapd.db failed to download
error: failed retrieving file 'snapd.db' from dl-cdn.alpin : Could not resolve host: dl-cdn.alpin
warning: fatal error from dl-cdn.alpin, skipping for the remainder of this transaction
error: failed to synchronize all databases (failed to retrieve some files)

